# User is not notified on how to open column menu on ag grid

Tags: accessibility, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Users can open a column menu with just the keyboard, using the CTRL and ENTER keys.

The issue I ran into is users are not notified how to open the column menu with just the keyboard.  If the user uses an accessibility application such as NVDA, there is no `aria-label` or `aria-description` to notify the user how to open it with the keyboard. Is this an ADA defect?

Note that I added an `aria-description` myself and that resolved the issue for column headers that don't have the header checkbox. If the column header has a header checkbox, the `aria-describedby` prevents the `aria-description` and `aria-label` from being read.

The `aria-describedby: ag-29-input` on the columnheader div doesn't appear to do anything and is also on the input for the checkbox. Setting `aria-describedby` to an empty string on the column header fixes the issue where `aria-describedby: ag-29-input` prevents aria-description and aria-label from being read on NVDA.

Answer (score 0):

How does a sighted user know to press Ctrl+Enter?  Are there any instructions for them?

I looked up some ag-grid examples on https://codesandbox.io/examples/package/ag-grid-react (because I wasn't familiar with it) and I ran the "[AG Grid React with Key-Value Data](https://6lywh.csb.app/)" demo.  The columns in the table had an `aria-description` of *"Press CTRL ENTER to open column menu."*

```html
<div class="ag-header-cell ag-focus-managed" role="columnheader" tabindex="-1" aria-colindex="3" col-id="mealTime" aria-description="Press CTRL ENTER to open column menu.">
```

So the screen reader user will actually have an advantage over the sighted user because they'll hear the keyboard shortcut instructions.  The sighted user won't have any instructions regarding the keyboard shortcuts.

I'm not sure if the person that created that demo added `aria-description` or if it's built into the ag-grid.

**Note** that `aria-description` isn't official yet.  It's still in the AIRA 1.3 "[Editor's Draft](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#aria-description)" spec.  [ARIA 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/) is the current official spec and [ARIA 1.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.2/) is in the "Candidate Recommendation" phase.  So I was surprised that the `aria-description` example worked with NVDA.

In any event, both sighted keyboard users and low vision or blind screen reader users **both** should be notified about the keyboard shortcut.  If the user cannot navigate to the column header and open the menu, whether via a shortcut key or some other keypress, then yes, it would be an ADA issue.  It would fail [WCAG 2.1.1 Keyboard](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#keyboard).

Answer (score 0):

When focusing a column header cell in AG Grid, screen readers (NVDA, JAWS) announce the keyboard shortcut to open the column menu to end-users if the column menu is available (it's an AG Grid Enterprise-only feature).

I'm not sure why there's no announcement on your end, as this has been announced correctly for quite a while now. Please submit an issue on the AG Grid github page with instructions on how we can reproduce this behavior and we'll investigate.

As for a list of keyboard shortcuts for sighted users - the keyboard shortcuts which can be used in AG Grid are listed here:
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/keyboard-navigation/#normal-column-headers

Please review this keyboard shortcuts list and include the relevant shortcuts in your messaging to your end-users on how to use your application more effectively.